Smooth By UV Islands
I would like to know what object -> Smooth By UV Islands does?
For me removes the seams that show in marmoset when I import the fbx. But at the same time seems to put random sharp edges, and I think is messing with the model when I bake in marmoset. But I don't really know. Well if some can explain to me what that option does I will appreciated it, it puts some artifacts or shading effects on the mesh. Also I'm new to all this. Thank you.

I would assume that this means it treats all boundary edges of UV islands as sharp edges and smoothes only within the UV islands. But since you do not show any screenshots in your question it is hard to tell if there are "random" sharp edges or if they do make any sense. Anyway, I do not find Smooth By UV Islands in my Object menu, neither in 4.2.2 nor in 4.3.2, so I can only guess what it does.
